# validate input data with symfony, doctrine or zend_validate?

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony1, doctrine, zend-validate

im using symfony with doctrine and zend.

i wonder if i wanna validate the user input data, should i use validation from symfony, zend or even doctrine?

i think i should go with symfony, but are there times the validation from zend or doctrine would be better?

thanks

Comment: Use any one validator that does the job and that integrates best into your application. You can also use the native filter functions: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you create your forms.

If you use the form framework of symfony, there's no reason not to use it for validation as well.

If you use Zend_Form, I guess you're better off validating with Zend.

Also: doctrine only validates data such as "this has to be an integer" or "this has to be a string <50 characters long", the form framework can do much more than that.